# geopandas: A clone created destroys properties of parent file

Tags: python, geopandas

I have carried out the execution of the following code and unfortunately ended up in a situation where the parent variable data is modified when I edit another variable.

code is as follows:

```
filename="../foobar.shp"     #........ import any shapefile

db_file1 = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file(filename)

db_file2=db_file1  #Equating one geopandas to another,essentially creating a copy

db_file2.code=(db_file2.code*2) #Where "code" is a valid column header

print (db_file2,"\n",db_file1)
```

the output shows that db_file1 has been modified, even though nothing like that has been done.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You did not make a copy, you pointed two variables to the same object in memory. In order to make a copy you should use

`df2 = df.copy()`